# Rigging a sculpted character

Tags: rigging

I am new to Blender and have done a few tutorials to learn the basics, mainly creating objects, a water well, some basic shapes and my next project is looking at base meshes for characters. I am currently following a great one about character creation and sculpting. My next plan is to learn rigging.
Can I rig a full character created with sculpted detail? I am struggling to see how you go from a styled and designed character to then rig it.

Comment: Your best bet is to try.  Find a tutorial, follow along, and ask specific questions here if you get stuck :)

Comment: You'd better not rig a sculpted character, it probably has a high amount of polygons, which is not good for animation and rendering, you'd better bake its normal and prepare a low-poly version (see retopology), then rig the low-poly